# How to do a basic contextualization in JavaScript using nlp-compromise?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, nlp, nlp-compromise

So I saw this awesome [natural language processing in javascript](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/compromise) and I wonder how can I do a basic contextualization?

Let's say for example, I want to get the time.

By doing something like this:

```
var word = nlp(`What's the time`)

console.log(word.match('time').found)
```

I get a `true` boolean since the `time` word is present. But what I wanted to do is for example

`nlp('What's the time')` and `nlp('What time is it')` the value will be true but if `nlp('Time is gold')` the value will be false since the user didn't ask for the time.

Is that possible with this library? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you want to do is **Intent Recognition**, which is usually treated as a classification problem. This [article](https://chatbotslife.com/text-classification-using-algorithms-e4d50dcba45) gives an overview of one way to do it; take a look at the training data:

```
training_data.append({"class":"greeting", "sentence":"how are you?"})
training_data.append({"class":"greeting", "sentence":"how is your day?"})
training_data.append({"class":"greeting", "sentence":"good day"})
training_data.append({"class":"greeting", "sentence":"how is it going today?"})

training_data.append({"class":"goodbye", "sentence":"have a nice day"})
training_data.append({"class":"goodbye", "sentence":"see you later"})
training_data.append({"class":"goodbye", "sentence":"have a nice day"})
training_data.append({"class":"goodbye", "sentence":"talk to you soon"})

training_data.append({"class":"sandwich", "sentence":"make me a sandwich"})
training_data.append({"class":"sandwich", "sentence":"can you make a sandwich?"})
training_data.append({"class":"sandwich", "sentence":"having a sandwich today?"})
training_data.append({"class":"sandwich", "sentence":"what's for lunch?"})
```

Compromise doesn't have any features for text classification so it won't help you here.

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

yeah, like [polm23 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44838797/168877), this feels like a statistical classification problem.

but, if you knew, (or machine-learned) sentence-templates that suggest the intent, you could locate them in compromise with the [match syntax](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/compromise/wiki/Match-syntax)

```
//what time is..
if(doc.has('#QuestionWord time #Copula')){
  return true
}
//time is fun..
if(doc.has('time #Copula #Adjective')){
  return false
}
```